# Navigation controller background image repeat it self in ios 11 using xcode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, xcode9

I had tried following code to set background image of `UINavigationBar`.
It was working fine before Xcode 9 but in Xcode 9 image are not set properly.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"headr_bg"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

[Xcode 9 image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXy2y.png)

[Xcode 9 image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPMrK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPMrK.png)

[[before Xcode 9]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAx0u.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be its not perfect solution & 
but i had old project in that i had fixed it by below code. Just updated navigation bar position and navigation view frame for ios version > 11.

```
CGRect navbarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
CGRect navFrame = self.navigationController.view.frame;
navbarFrame.size.height = 44;
navFrame.origin.y = 20;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = navbarFrame;
self.navigationController.view.frame = navFrame;
```

Comment: Setting the navigationBar frame solved my Xcode 9 nav bar woes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue however I could not find a fix working with insets or with a layout based approach. Ultimately a quick work around was to create a secondary background image and pad the top of the original background with 20px with the previous color of your status bar (black in your case).

Then I simply added code to change the image depending if this is iOS 11+ like so:

```
NSString* navBarImg = @"navbar.png";

if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    navBarImg = @"navbar_ios11.png";
}

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:navBarImg] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This may not work or may need tweaks depending if the status bar visibility is shown/hidden at some points. Hopefully this will help until a better approach is discovered.